# Flyby Venus (graph not showing)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, physics

My goal is to model the gravitational assistance (flyby, slingshot) exerted by Venus on a satellite, I wrote the corresponding program but the problem is that my graph is not displayed. I want to represent the evolution of the speed of the satellite as a function of time during the passage near Venus but I cannot understand why my graph is not displayed...

```
import math as m
import random as rd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


omega=3.23639*10**(-7) #rad/s
r_venus=1.08209*10**11 #m
phi=0.3 #par exemple # en radian
Gms=1.32724*10**20 #N.m²/kg
Gmv=3.24916*10**14 #N.m²/kg

def eval_sm(x,y,t):
    Sx=-Gms*x/(x**2+y**2)**(3/2)-Gmv*(x-r_venus*m.cos(omega*t+phi))/((x-r_venus*m.cos(omega*t+phi))**2+(y-r_venus*m.sin(omega*t+phi))**2)**(3/2)
    Sy=-Gms*y/(x**2+y**2)**(3/2)-Gmv*(y-r_venus*m.sin(omega*t+phi))/((x-r_venus*m.cos(omega*t+phi))**2+(y-r_venus*m.sin(omega*t+phi))**2)**(3/2)
return Sx,Sy


x=[0]
y=[1.1*10**11]
u=[-500]
v=[0]
delta_t=1
n=30*24*3600
t=[i*delta_t for i in range(n)]



for i in range(1,n):
    x.append(x[i-1]+delta_t*u[i-1])
    y.append(y[i-1]+delta_t*v[i-1])
    Sx,Sy=eval_sm(x[i-1],y[i-1],t[i-1])
    u.append(u[i-1]+Sx*delta_t)
    v.append(v[i-1]+Sy*delta_t)




def vitesse_sonde(u,v,t):
    vitesse=[]
    for i in range(len(u)):
        vitesse.append(m.sqrt(u[i]**2+v[i]**2)/1000) # mettre en km
    plt.plot(t,vitesse)
    plt.xlabel('temps en seconde')
    plt.ylabel('vitesse en km/s')
    plt.title('vitesse de la sonde')
    plt.show()
```

Edit:

when I writing

```
    vitesse_sonde(u,v,t)
```

I get this curve:

[image]

While I'm looking to get something like this[image]

My problem when I try to extract the component x from the speed which is written Sx and well I have an error which comes out of the type:

[image]

[image]

Comment: you need to call the function `vitesse_sonde`

Comment: @warped I'm not getting the curve I want...look at my updating post please...

Comment: Are you asking about how to plot multiple lines or how to generate that data?

Comment: @PaulH how to generate that data. How do I get the X and Y components of the velocity? I know I need to get them with eval_sm but I can't seem to call the function because it throws me an error

Comment: @AspiringPhysicist search for "components of a vector"

Comment: @PaulH I am in the second year at the University of Physics, I still know what a vector component is. There the problem comes from my way of coding, you do not see where I can fix the error which is displayed on the screen please? I read on the documentation, and I tried to convert my Gms and Gmv values to str then convert them to float when I call them in the eval function but it still doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Your example code runs w/o error for me

Comment: Why would you expect multiple curves when you only plot `vitesse` vs `t` with `plt.plot(t,vitesse)`?

Comment: @Mr.T I know... What I rather ask is to be able to plot Sx and Sy but I have a problem when I try to get values with my eval function...